# I have a syntax error while creating a function and i am not sure what I have got wrong

Tags: python

I am a beginner for python and I have a syntax error while creating a function, I need some help to find what I have got wrong.

This is for a Ture False quiz function for returning Turn or False after input question and answer.

```
your_ans = input('entering your answer: t or f：')
def tf_quiz(question, correct_ans):
    if correct_answer == your_ans
        print ('your answer is correct')
    else:
        print('your answer is incorrect')
```

I expect the function to work as I can use the function with tf_quiz but it turns out to be a syntax error

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: Missing `:` at the end of line 3?

Comment: if correct_answer == your_ans
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: omg yesss!!!@https://stackoverflow.com/users/6866811/thesilkworm thx a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon to the line

```py
    if correct_answer == your_ans:
```

Comment: @YiYuanLi If you find answers helpful, it's a good idea to upvote them. This is a tiny thank you and an indicator to later readers. It's also a good idea to "accept" the answer you find most helpful if there is an answer which completely answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the colon on the end of your `if` statement. Code should be:

```
your_ans = input('entering your answer: t or f：')
def tf_quiz(question, correct_ans):
    if correct_answer == your_ans:
        print('your answer is correct')
    else:
        print('your answer is incorrect')
```